# Python's datetime: "AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'strptime'"

Tags: python-datetime

I'm trying to convert a string `date_str = '01-01-2000'` to a date object, and want to compare with a given date.

I used `my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d-%m-%Y")` which works, until I try to compare with a given date:

```
    if my_date <= other_date:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
```

When I change datetime to date and do `datetime.date.strptime(date_str, "%d-%m-%Y")`, I get `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'strptime'`:

```
datetime.date.strptime(date_str, "%d-%m-%Y")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There indeed is no `strptime()` for a `datetime.date` object, and there is no `strpdate()` function either.

Just use `datetime.strptime()` and convert to a date object afterwards:

```
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d-%m-%Y").date()
```